# Mcpe IP can't add colon symbol

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to join a server but I can't seem to add the colon symbol `:` in the "IP Address" textbox. The IP Address of the server has a colon symbol in it.

Comment: The colon in an IP-address marks a [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29) being used. Seems that the default (assumed) port MCPE uses is 19132. If the number after the colon is that, you should be able to ignore it (and the colon). If not... We'll, I hope someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: You could write the IP down into a text editor, copy the IP and paste it in to Minecraft, which would be done via CTRL+V.

Comment: @LittleHelper, This is MCPE, aka iOS and Android versions, which commonly don't use Ctrl+V for pasting... However it _could_ be possible to use the OS' default pasting options.